# Add a new element to a JSON array using jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a json as mentioned in the first section and i want to add an element("image": "<IMAGE1_NAME>",) in the json as specified in the expected output.

I tired to use jq like this:

```
'.containerDefinitions += {"operation":"delete"}'
```

but this seem to not work. can anyone help me the jq command to achieve the result i want.

```
{
"taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws",
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "dev-service",
        "cpu": 0,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 8080,
                "hostPort": 8080,
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }
        ],
        "essential": true,
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "message",
                "value": "Hi, EMC!!"
            }
        ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

expected output :

```
{
"taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:619867110810:task-definition/emc-dev-backend:30",
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "dev-service",
        "image": "<IMAGE1_NAME>",
        "cpu": 0,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 8080,
                "hostPort": 8080,
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }
        ],
        "essential": true,
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "message",
                "value": "Hi, EMC!!"
            }
        ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's an array, we'll need some sort of loop, use

```
.containerDefinitions[] += { "image":"IMAGE1_NAME" }
```

To add `{ "image":"IMAGE1_NAME" }` on each item in the `containerDefinitions` key

---

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/A9StRkIJMA)

Answer (score 0):

Your input JSON is not formatted correctly. Assuming your actual input is

```json
{
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "dev-service",
      "cpu": 0,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 8080,
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "message",
          "value": "Hi, EMC!!"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

which would mean that `containerDefinitions` is an array, not an object. Thus, to add an object **as another array item**, go with

```sh
jq '.containerDefinitions += [{"image":"<IMAGE1_NAME>"}]'
```

```json
{
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "dev-service",
      "cpu": 0,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 8080,
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "message",
          "value": "Hi, EMC!!"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "image": "<IMAGE1_NAME>"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/gBDZ9C7SDb)

If, however, you wanted to merge that object into one of the array items (if to all of them, use `[]` instead of `[0]`), go with

```sh
jq '.containerDefinitions[0] += {"image":"<IMAGE1_NAME>"}'
```

```json
{
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "dev-service",
      "cpu": 0,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 8080,
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "message",
          "value": "Hi, EMC!!"
        }
      ],
      "image": "<IMAGE1_NAME>"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/g4S9KTETeM)